# MongoDB filename executed

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I wonder if it is possible to get the filename of the javascript executed.

I mean I need to excecuted;

```
mongo host/db myJSfile.js
```

So at myJSfile.js

```
myName = db.getXXXX()
```

at myName get the filename?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get file name from mongo shell you can cheat by using `--eval` and js file at the same time, like this:

```
mongo --eval "jsFileName='myJSfile.js'" myJSfile.js
```

And after that you can write in your `myJSfile.js`:

```
function printJavaScriptFileName()
{
    if (jsFileName)
    {
        print(jsFileName);
    }
}
```